Spring Gateway timeout issue
I have this simple spring boot application controller:
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomerController {
    
    final CustomerService customerService;
    
    @GetMapping("/customer")
    public boolean checkAvailable() {
        return true;
    }
}

With postman I can get a simple 200 response with GET request to http://localhost:8081/customer
Here is my Spring Gateway app config:
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class RouteConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                      .route(r -> r.path("/customer")
                                   .uri("http://localhost:8081"))
                      .build();
    }
}

However I cannot get a response on http://localhost:8080/customer It simply times out after 10 seconds. Any ideas?
Funnily enough, if I add a Eureka Server in and make sure both applications register with it then use loadbalanced url lb:// the request works. Does this mean the gateway will not serve local host addresses?
